# Is there a way to BDD Ruby Shoes?

Tags: ruby, bdd, shoes

I'm looking for some solutions to BDD a new Shoes app. Any suggestions

Comment: Can't really help with an answer as I don't understand Behaviour Driven Development (over my head). However, BDD was the last question on the old Shoes mailing list, perhaps some pointers there: http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.shoes/4121

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try to build everything not directly related to UI into PORCs (Plain Old Ruby Classes) and BDD those in the usual way, `require`-ing them into shoes later. I suspect you're thinking about the GUI parts, though, and I can't help there. All test/behaviour-driven development seems to be somewhat challenged by the GUI aspect, Ruby at least as much as any other and shoes quite possibly more than most Ruby frameworks.